# How to call variadic function with some parameters before variadic parameter using hy?

Tags: hy

I am trying to write something similar to:

```
@classmethod
def write(cls, records, values, *args):
    return super(Hello, cls).write(records, values, *args)
```

But I have issues with passing the *args back.
I tried using apply (but cannot pass the record and values).
I also tried to use apply with partial without success.

Current not working code in hylang:

```
(with-decorator classmethod
    (defn write [cls records values &rest args]
      (.write (super Hello cls) records values args)
      ))
```

In clojure normally I would write:

```
(apply .write (super Hello cls) records values args)
```

But it seems apply in hy doesn't support arguments before *args.

How can I write the original python code in hy?

Answer (score 0):

I updated to latest version of hy

```
pip install git+https://github.com/hylang/hy.git
```

In this latest version apply has been replaced with #*

> `apply` has been replaced with Python-style unpacking operators `#*` and
>   `#**` (e.g., `(f #* args #** kwargs)`)

On the new version of hy the code can be written as:

```
(with-decorator classmethod
(defn write [cls records values &rest args]
  (.write (super Hello cls) records values #* args)
  ))
```